# Package to vizualize clustering in python or Java?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, package, data-visualization, agent-based-modeling

I am doing an agent based modeling and currently have this set up in Python, but I can switch over to Java if necessary.
I have a dataset on Twitter (11 million nodes and 85 million directed edges), and I have set up a dictionary/hashmap so that the key is a specific user A and its value is a list of all the followers (people that follow user A). The "nodes" are actually just the integer ID numbers (unique), and there is no other data. I want to be able to visualize this data through some method of clustering. Not all individual nodes have to be visualized, but I want the nodes with the n most followers to be visualized clearly, and the surrounding area around that node would represent all the people who follow it. I'm modeling the spread of something throughout the map, so I need the nodes and areas around the nodes to change colors. Ideally, it would be a continuous visualization, but I don't mind it just taking snapshots at every ith iteration.
Additionally, I was thinking of having the clusters be separated such that:
if person A and person B have enough followers to be visualized individually, and person A and B are connected (one follows the other or maybe even both ways), then they are both visualized, but are visually separated from each other despite being connected so that the visualization is clearer.

Anyways, I was wondering whether there was a package in Python (preferably) or Java that would allow one to do this semi easily.

Answer (score 0):

[Gephi](https://gephi.org/) has a very nice GUI and an associated [Java toolkit](https://gephi.org/toolkit/). You can experiment with visual layout in the GUI until you have everything looking the way you like and then code up your own version using the toolkit.